How to check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'log2'
I have a problem for my power allocation code in Matlab. When i run the code, it produced an error. I've already checked the the values/types of the two variables passed to log2. I put a breakpoint at the line that's getting the error.
The line that give me error is: R_tilde_1 = Bandwidth*log2(R_tilde_1_sum + Sigma_n^2); I've checked the values/types of the variables passed to log2. The value of R_tilde_1_sum is cvx real affine expression (scalar). The value of Sigma_n is 7.9621e-15.
Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'log2'.

Error in power_allocation_MM (line 117)
        R_tilde_1 = Bandwidth*log2(R_tilde_1_sum + Sigma_n^2); % first term of Eq. (12)

Error in main_BellmanFord (line 11)
P = power_allocation_MM(A);

Can somebody help and show me on where i did wrong. This is the most of the code for power_allocation_MM(A).m :
        % Variable initilization
        R_tilde_2_sum = 0;
        R_tilde_3_sum_1 =0;
        R_tilde_3_sum_2 = 0;
    
        % Find all the users associate to the same BS
        Ass_BS = find(Ass_matrix(:,j));    % index of the associate BS of the current user
        if isempty(Ass_BS)  % this user is out
            Tx_rate_cvx(1,j) = 0;
            continue;
        else
            Num_user = Num_user + 1;
        end
   
        Ass_user = [];  % index of all the users associate to the same BS
        for i=1:N
            if Ass_matrix(Ass_BS,i) == 1 && i ~= j
                Ass_user  = [Ass_user,i];
            end
        end
               
        % Find all the users on the same sub-channel
        Ass_group = find(Group_matrix(:,j));  % index of the group of the current user
        Gro_user = [];      % index of all the users on the same sub-channel
        for i =1:length(Ass_user)
            if Group_matrix(Ass_group,Ass_user(i)) == 1 
                Gro_user = [Gro_user,Ass_user(i)];
            end
        end
                   
        % Find all the users decode behind the current user
        S_cur = S(j);
        Beh_user = [];
        for i =1:length(Gro_user)
            if S((Gro_user(i))) > S_cur
                Beh_user = [Beh_user,Gro_user(i)];
            end
        end
           
        for i=1:length(Beh_user)
            R_tilde_2_sum = R_tilde_2_sum + abs(sum(Channel_coff(:,Beh_user(i)).*A(:,Beh_user(i))))^2*P_last(Beh_user(i));
        end
        R_tilde_1_sum = R_tilde_2_sum + abs(sum(Channel_coff(:,j).*A(:,j)))^2*P_cvx(j);
        R_tilde_2 = Bandwidth*log2(R_tilde_2_sum + Sigma_n^2); % second term of Eq. (12)
        R_tilde_1 = Bandwidth*log2(R_tilde_1_sum + Sigma_n^2); % first term of Eq. (12)
    
        for i=1:length(Beh_user)
            R_tilde_3_sum_2 = R_tilde_3_sum_2 + abs(sum(Channel_coff(:,Beh_user(i)).*A(:,Beh_user(i))))^2*(P_last(Beh_user(i)));  % denominator of the third term of Eq. (12)
        end

        R_tilde_3_sum_2 = R_tilde_3_sum_2 + Sigma_n^2;

        for i=1:length(Beh_user)
            R_tilde_3_sum_1 = R_tilde_3_sum_1 + abs(sum(Channel_coff(:,Beh_user(i)).*A(:,Beh_user(i))))^2*(P_cvx(Beh_user(i))-P_last(Beh_user(i))); % molecule of the third term of Eq. (12)
        end

        R_tilde_3 = Bandwidth* 1/log(2) * (R_tilde_3_sum_1 / R_tilde_3_sum_2);
    
        Tx_rate_cvx(1,j) = R_tilde_1 - R_tilde_2 - R_tilde_3;  % Eq. (12) for the j-th user
        Weighted_Tx_rate_cvx(1,j) = Tx_rate_cvx(1,j) * Weight(1,N); 


Put a breakpoint at the line that's getting the error. Check the values/types of the two variables passed to log2. Do they make sense? If you can't find the error there, as @Cris said, we'll need an executable example that we can use to reproduce the error. As of now, there are undefined variables in your code.

if any of the vectors used to build the arguments of log2 contain NaN, are complex, or have not been defined, it's likely that log2 returns error.

“I've already checked the the values/types of the two variables passed to log2” What are their values? Remember that part of a [mre] is the minimal part. Try to make it simple for us to see what is going on by simplifying the code, removing irrelevant stuff, etc. The other part is reproducible, where we can copy-paste the code into MATLAB and see the error it produces. If we can’t do that, we don’t know what is happening in the code. You use lots of undefined variables in this bit of code, meaning we don’t know what is going into the log2 call, so don’t know why that input is wrong.

I put a breakpoint at the line that's getting the error. The line that give me error is: R_tilde_1 = Bandwidth*log2(R_tilde_1_sum + Sigma_n^2); I've checked the values/types of the variables passed to log2. The value of R_tilde_1_sum is cvx real affine expression (scalar). The value of Sigma_n is 7.9621e-15.
